# Make regex quantifier length depend on previous capture group

Tags: regex, rust

I'm hoping to use a regex to parse strings which begin with an integer *n*. After a space, there are *n* characters, after which there may be more text. I'm hoping to capture *n* and the *n* characters that follow. There are no constraints on these *n* characters. In other words, `5 hello world` should match with the capture groups `5` and `hello`.

I tried this regex, but it wouldn't compile because its structure depends on the input: `(\d+) .{\1}`.

Is there a way to get the regex compiler to do what I want, or do I have to parse this myself?

I'm using Rust's `regex` crate, if that matters. And if it's not possible with `regex`, is it possible with another, more sophisticated regex engine?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to convert a string such as `"5"` to the integer it represents, `5`. You can't do that with a regex. What is the maximum value of `n`?

Comment: `n` is a 32-bit integer, but that could change for the sake of a convenient solution.

Comment: You could a simple regular expression to get `n`, then in code convert it to an integer and extract then strings of interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Cary Swoveland said in the comments, this is not possible in regex in one step without hard-coding the various possible lengths.

However, it is not too difficult to take a substring of the matched string with length from the matched digit:

```
use regex::Regex;
    
fn main() {
    let re = Regex::new(r"(\d+) (.+)").unwrap();
    let test_str = "5 hello world";

    for cap in re.captures_iter(test_str) {
        let length: usize = cap[1].parse().unwrap_or(0);
        let short_match: String = cap[2].chars().take(length).collect();

        println!("{}", short_match); // hello
    }
}
```

If you know you'll only be dealing with ASCII characters (no Unicode, accent marks, etc.) then you can use the simpler slice syntax `let short_match = &cap[2][..length];`.

Comment: You can simplify your code somewhat by using capture indexing. e.g., `cap[1].parse().unwrap_or(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

If `Perl` is your option, would you please try:

```
perl -e '
$str = "5 abcdefgh";
$str =~ /(\d+) ((??{".{".($^N)."}"}))/;
print "1st capture group = $1\n";
print "2nd capture group = $2\n";
print "whole capture group = $&\n";
'
```

Output:

```
1st capture group = 5
2nd capture group = abcde
whole capture group = 5 abcde
```

[Explanation]

- If the `(??{...})` block is encountered in a regex, its contents
  are expanded as a `Perl` code on the fly.
- The special variable `$^N` refers to the `last captured group`
  and is expanded as `5` in the case.
- Then the code `(??{".{".($^N)."}"})` is evaluated as `.{5}` which
  represents a dot followed by a quantifier.