# How to match the pattern the number of the character of group A more than group B only using Regex?

Tags: regex

For example, I want to match the patterns such as follows:

1. AAAB
2. AAABB
3. AAB

Does not match the patterns such as follows:

1. AAABBBB
2. ABB
3. AABBB

As the examples above, the occurrence of the character B should be fewer than the character A.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make regex quantifier length depend on previous capture group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62707587/make-regex-quantifier-length-depend-on-previous-capture-group)

Answer (score 0):

Consider instead comparing the group lengths **after** matching, rather than differentiating the group lengths directly in the regex!

Example in Python:

```py
for test_string in collection_of_strings:
    match = re.match(RE_myregex, test_string)
    if not match:          # regex did not match at all
        continue           # jump to top of loop to try next string
    a, b = match.groups()  # unpack match groups
    if len(b) >= len(a):   # must be fewer B than A
        continue
    # work with a and b
```

Comment: so it can't be achieved only with regex?

Comment: It's probably possible with a clever backreference (though you may need an extended regular expression lib) and certainly a valid and interesting question for it, regardless of possibility! However, it's likely your code will be both harder to read and less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Probably best to just use pattern length and compare as @ti7 did.

It is possible to use regex, however regex has no concept of variable length back-reference. Nevertheless, you can do the test first for two As, then 3 As, then 4 As, up to the level you need. Here is a JavaScript example that test up to 4 As. As a bonus, it tests for any type of character sequence, followed by any other character sequence:

```js
const input =[
  'AAB',
  'AABB',
  'AABBB',
  'AAAB',
  'AAABB',
  'AAABBB',
  'AAABBBB',
  'AAAAB',
  'AAAABB',
  'AAAABBB',
  'AAAABBBB',
  'AAAAAB',
  'AAAAABB',
  'AAAAABBB',
  'AAAAABBBB',
  'AAAAABBBBB',
];
const regex = /^(?:(.)\1(?![^\1]{2})|(.)\2\2(?![^\2]{3})|(.)\3\3\3(?![^\3]{4})|(.)\4\4\4\4(?![^\4]{5}))/;
input.forEach(str => {
  console.log(str + ' => ' + regex.test(str));
});
```

Output:

```
AAB => true
AABB => false
AABBB => false
AAAB => true
AAABB => true
AAABBB => false
AAABBBB => false
AAAAB => true
AAAABB => true
AAAABBB => true
AAAABBBB => false
AAAAAB => true
AAAAABB => true
AAAAABBB => true
AAAAABBBB => true
AAAAABBBBB => false
```

Explanation for regex:

- `(?:` ... `|` ... `|` ... `|` ...) - non-capturing OR group
- `(.)\1(?![^\1]{2})`:

  - `(.)` capture any character
  - `\1` expect the same character again
  - `(?![^\1]{2})` - negative lookahead for two identical character NOT matched before
- `(.)\2\2(?![^\2]{3})`:

  - `(.)` capture any character (second capture group)
  - `\2\2` expect the same character again, and again
  - `(?![^\2]{3})` - negative lookahead for three identical character NOT matched before
- rinse & repeat as many times as you need

Answer (score 0):

A regex based solution for a PCRE compatible engine. (should support subroutine & lookarounds).

The pattern is indeed a bit complex and as mentioned in other answers may be custom code is the right choice for your scenario.

**Approach**:

- Match first 'A'.
- Post that in recursion each `A` can be paired with a `B`

**Demo:** https://regex101.com/r/n6IFQ9/6

**Pattern:**

```
^(?'r'(.)
         (?>(?=\2)(?&r)(.|$)(?=\3|$)
         |)
)$
```

**Breakdown:**

- `(?'r'...)` : Define a subroutine named `r`.
- `(.)` : Match any character. Capture it in a group `\2`
- `(?=\2)(?&r)(.|$)(?=\3|$)` : Either the next character matches current.

  - `(?=\2)`: 'Positive lookahead' to check if next character matches `\2`. (True till the first `B`).
  - `(?&r)` : call subroutine `r`. (Recursion)
  - `(.|$)(?=\3|$)` : This will be matched post recursion.

    - Match `.` or `$` and capture it in `\3`.
    - It should be followed by `\3` or `$`.
- Or return success (for first `B`)